# Buscar mais dados após não encontrar nada referente a ID

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, matriz

Estou fazendo um sistema de matriz 4x4 para um cliente e estou tendo uma dificuldade na seguinte questão: O sistema tem que verificar se o indicado a ser checado já tem 4 pessoas na rede, se houver então procura no próximo indicado ao lado, até o fim. Caso não houver retorna uma mensagem falando que tem uma vaga disponível.

Veja a foto: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGljo.png

O sistema verifica no nível 1: Como visto na foto tem 4
O sistema então verifica no primeiro usuário (**Bruno**) se abaixo dele (nivel 2) tem 4, se não tiver retorna uma mensagem falando que tem vaga. Na foto tem 4 em baixo de **Bruno**, então o certo seria ele verificar no **João Vitor** (ao lado), só que ao invez disso, o sistema procura abaixo de **Julia** que é indicada de **Bruno**.

Tenho o código

```
public function QuantidadeLinhasMatriz($id, $nivel = 1){

            $this->db->where('id_patrocinador', $id);
            $patrocinadores = $this->db->get('patrocinadores');

            if($patrocinadores->num_rows() >= 4){

                foreach($patrocinadores->result() as $row){

                    echo $this->QuantidadeLinhasMatriz($row->id_usuario, $nivel+1).'<br />';
            }

            }else{
                return 'Nivel '.$nivel.' disponivel na ID '.$id;
            }
    }
```

Como pode ser visto no lado superior esquerdo do print, está impresso:

```
Nivel 3 disponivel na ID 9
Nivel 3 disponivel na ID 10
Nivel 3 disponivel na ID 11
Nivel 3 disponivel na ID 12

Nivel 2 disponivel na ID 7
Nivel 2 disponivel na ID 8
Nivel 2 disponivel na ID 17
```

O script até que está executando corretamente, mas ele já está verificando o terceiro nível (sem acabar de verificar todo o segundo nível) e o que ele precisava só me retornar era `Nivel 2 disponivel na ID 7`

**Resumindo:** Ele tem que verificar no nível atual se em um dos membros que estão nesse nível tem 4 pessoas, se tiver, vai para o membro que está ao lado, até o final. Se todos retornarem que tem 4 ou mais, então desce mais um nível e faz a mesma verificação.

Comment: Você está selecionando o 2 nível do mesmo usuário? por que quando você entra no loop de um usuário que já possui quatro abaixo dele esse código está indo para o primeiro desses  4 abaixo de Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma adaptação do seu código, pois eu não tenho o database, acho que ficaria algo do tipo, é claro que não estou passando o nível como parâmetro na função.

```
      function QuantidadeLinhasMatriz( $usuarios, $contador  ){
            $tempArray = array();
            foreach( $usuarios as $k => $v ){

                       if ( is_array( $v ) and count($v) == 4 )
                        {  
                            $contador = 1;
                            echo "  \$usuarios[$k] => $v NAO TEM VAGA.\n   |"; 
                            continue;   
                        }

                       $tempArray =  $v;
                       if ( count( $k ) < 4  ){
                           echo "$v TEM VAGA     |"; 
                           $contador = 1;
                           continue;
                        }

                      echo "  $usuarios[$k] => $v.\n";
                      $contador += 1; 

                       QuantidadeLinhasMatriz( $tempArray, $contador );


            }    
    }
```

$usuarios = array( 'Bruno' =>array( 'Júlia', 'Geremias', 'Leo', 'Feranda' ), 'João Victor', 'Vinicius', 'Andressa' );

QuantidadeLinhasMatriz( $usuarios, 1 );

Comment: Preenchi os outros nomes `(João Victor, Vinicius e Andressa)` como se tivessem 4 também como o Bruno e ele não me exibe nada. O certo seria então ele procurar dentro de `Júlia` agora, pois ele não achou em nenhum dos outros (primeira linha), então ele volta e procura dentro do Bruno Primeiro. entende ? de resto ta OK seu código

Answer (score 0):

Bom não testei esse código porque não tenho como, talvez precise fazer ajustes, mas a ideia é fazer um loop por fora com o níveis permitidos para cada iteração.

```
$nivelInicial   = getNivelMinimo(Patrocinador); // TO-Do
$nivelMaximo    = getNivelMaximo(Patrocinador); // TO-Do
$nivelPermitido = $nivelInicial +1;
$contador = $nivelInicial;

 public function QuantidadeLinhasMatriz($id, $nivel = 1, $permitido ){

            $this->db->where('id_patrocinador', $id);
            $patrocinadores = $this->db->get('patrocinadores');

            if($patrocinadores->num_rows() >= 4){

                foreach($patrocinadores->result() as $row){

                    if ( $nivel > $permitido )
                       continue;

                    echo $this->QuantidadeLinhasMatriz($row->id_usuario, $nivel+1 ).'<br />';
            }

            }else{
                return 'Nivel '.$nivel.' disponivel na ID '.$id;
            }
    }

 while ( $contador  <= $nivelMaximo ){
        QuantidadeLinhasMatriz( $id_patrocinador, $nivelInicial, $nivelPermitido );
        $nivelInicial += 2;
        $contador += 2;
        $nivelPermitido++; 
}
```